# Menu item change position in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to certain menu item display on different position, for example there is demonstrate on picture

[image]

I want login and register to place on header line?

I tried using CSS but that's not semantically correct

Comment: You would have to create a new menu and call it in the header in the top bar(or just hardcode the links in there). You won't be able to just move those 2 items from the current menu to the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

May be the way you looking out is not the proper way to isolate them from the menu.
All the menu items are wrapped within `ul` placed in `li` and you cannot actually seperate them to place elsewhere.

The better and the quickest way will be registering a new menu as **Header menu**
`register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));` and actually assigning **Register** and **Login** as menu item under Header Menu and displaying them at top navigation bar as: `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>`

Take a refrence https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, I created new menu with this menu items and that menu drop into Widget and widget place in header line!